# run daemon on startup/login if scheduled time is missed

Tags: osx, startup, daemon

I have a daemon/script that runs daily in macos Sierra, but I can't find a way to make it run if the computer was off at the scheduled time.  Specifically, I'd like:

- run script/daemon once a day at a X:00 am
- if computer is off/sleeping at X:00, runs immediately when it wakes
- if daemon misses scheduled runs (off for several days), it runs once immediately when it wakes

The first point is handled easily with:

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
        </dict>
```

Running on startup/login when the scheduled time is "missed" is not the (default) behavior of launch agents, despite the suggestion (and later correction) in this question:

https://superuser.com/questions/126907/how-can-i-get-a-script-to-run-every-day-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Which OS are you talking about? MacOS X? Please add this info to title because in modern Linux you handle it with systemd.timer

Comment: @user996142 osx.  will edit.

Comment: have you tried adding passing your script to the anacron daemon? Anacron is 'anachronistic' and is designed for systems that are not running 24x7.